# gedit: search and replace with regular expressions

Tags: gedit

I want to replace this with gedit:

```
 1299465 |  2003415 | 2015-09-06 05:35:34.59662+02
 1299449 |  2009400 | 2015-09-06 05:35:32.301683+02
 1299450 |  2008465 | 2015-09-06 05:35:32.451393+02
 1299457 |  2015211 | 2015-09-06 05:35:33.451049+02
```

to that:

```
2003415
2009400
2008465
2015211
```

How can I do this with gedit?

Background: I want to do it with gedit and not sed/python/.... since the replace needs to be done interactive.

Comment: So you want to strip off the outer fields?

Comment: @Oli yes I want to strip off the first and third column

Answer (score 77, accepted):

From the standard Replace box (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) you can use a little grouped regex to handle this:

- Search for: `.*\| (.*) \|.*`
- Replace with: `\1`
- Check the box that has "Match as regular expression"

This is on Gedit 3.10.4, the default version in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: not working with no other plugins

Comment: @AlexGreg Huh? This is with stock `gedit` on 14.04 as far as I can tell. I've nuked `~/.config/gedit` and it still works.

Comment: well..not my case..weird

Comment: @AlexGreg It works, you have to check the "Regular expression" checkbox tough

Comment: that's the thing..I don't have that checkbox..using `gedit 2.30.4`

Comment: Sounds like you're using an ancient version of Ubuntu, @AlexGreg. [Even 12.04 Precise —the oldest supported version of Ubuntu— is using 3.4.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gedit&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all).

Comment: @Oli yes, works great. I am happy :-)

Comment: This is a specific answer to a specific question. Is there any help for a more general test? I can't seem to capture a literal string.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the plugin advanced-find for gedit.

Install the plugin from [here](https://code.google.com/p/advanced-find/downloads/list).

The instructions (if you don't know it already) on how to implement a gedit plugin is [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/gedit-plugin-to-search-and-replace-in.html)

Then, use Oli's answer to strip the numbers you want from your question.

Comment: If you are running Mint, you will likely have an old version of gedit and then this is the best answer.