# Editor with python compatible regular expressions

Tags: python, text-editor, regex

I am searching an editor which supports the regex syntax like python does.

I want a GUI like gedit.

The old school editors vi, vim, emacs are no solution, since the editor should be easy to use.

I use PyCharm for software development, but sometimes I just want to do a a simple re.sub() on some content from the clipboard.

The tool gedit is not bad (except pressing ctrl-f again does not do what you usually intent) but unfortunately it does not support the python regex flavour.

I know that gedit support regular expressions. But Python flavor regex syntax is required!

Comment: see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/671745/544264) `gedit` does support regular expression

Comment: @Yaron I updated the question. I want Python Regex Flavor.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "gedit: search and replace with regular expressions" since this question has an additional requirement, which the other has not. AND this question is not fixed on gedit other editors could win, too.

Comment: @guettli [This answer](/a/671748/175814) suggests a plug-in for advanced text search patterns. It's written in Python so I'd expect it to use Python's regular expression engine and syntax.

Comment: @DavidFoerster yes, the answer you mention is an answer to this question. But I think this is no reason to close this answer. Both questions are different. The other focuses on gedit, this one not.

Comment: I don't understand why you think this question is a dupliate. The other question is strictly about gedit. This current question is about choosing the editor. I think you are too fast. Just because both questions contain the keywords "editor" and "regex", this does not mean that one is a duplicate of the other. I am deeply relaxed. Have a nice day, happy fast thinking :-)

Answer (score 2):

A quick search for "regular expression" in Synaptic gives me `kiki` and `redet` as regex editors/development tools, among others. Both seem to support Python syntax.

Comment: A quick search reveals a lot. Do you have used one of those editors for more than a week?